# how to change format of contact in android? 000-000-000 to 00000000

Tags: php, android

I am trying to add contact numbers to server from android device.
sample contact is (000)0000-000. I want the number in a simple format without braces.

Comment: Use string.replace((starting character),(ending character))

Answer (score 0):

U can use Regular expression to remove any special char or symbol and keep only digits
e.g

```
String ph = "(000)0000-000";
String simplePh = ph.replaceAll("\\D","");
System.out.println(simplePh);
```

Output : 0000000000